# How can I create a shortcut for an application pointing to a specific firebird database archive?

Tags: windows, delphi

How Can I create a shortcut for an application pointing to a specific firebird database archive?

Something like:

```
\\192.168.235.5\application\app.exe \\192.168.235.2:3050:C:\firebird\db.fdb
```

- *\\192.168.235.5\application\app.exe* -> path to application running Ok and don't have an client for client machine. All machine run application from server; and
- *\\192.168.235.2:3050:C:\firebird\db.fdb* -> illustration of the situation: database archive is stored in another machine.

I think I see a launcher years ago, when I worked with Windows, with this characters. Maybe in a machine that runs an bank's application where financial department took care tree enterprises. It was a 12 years. Now I am work constantly with Linux.

This application can run with different databases and client machines can have more than one shortcut.

Comment: It is not clear to what your question is, but I think it is not directly Firebird-related, but more how you accept and process command line options in a Delphi application, right? You may want to rephrase your question a bit to make that more clear, and also make sure to ask an explicit question in the body of your question, not only in the title.

Comment: Do you really mean [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS)? Or just a command prompt to add [parameters when calling an executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments)?

Comment: `"C:\\Windows\Temp"`? No double backslashes for local paths.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... If you problem is to "write a script" to run an application with parameters, then you are looking how to write a batch file (Text file with extension .bat). In that file you can enter the text you showed. Then you create a shortcut to put on the user desktop or in his start menu. The easiest to do that is to drag and drop the batch file using the right mouse button and drop on desktop then select "create shortcut here". If this is not what you asked then edit your question so that it becomes clear.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @fpiette. Shortcut is the term. Have you some idea how to do this?

Comment: Thank you Mr. @MarkRotteveel. I did the edition. I count on you.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @AmigoJack. I was thinking run the command by script, but it isn't a rule. It's not a problem to run it by a shortcut.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Stephan. To run by shortcut i don't need more this command.

Comment: @gmc_pecas Do you ask how to use Windows UI to create a shortcut or do you ask how a Delphi program can create a shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Here after a Delphi function to create a shortcut by code:

```
function CreateShellLink(
    const ATargetName  : String;
    const AArguments   : String;
    const ALinkFolder  : String;
    const ALinkName    : String;
    const ADescription : String): Boolean;
var
    ISLink       : IShellLink;
    IPFile       : IPersistFile;
    LinkFileName : String;
    hr           : HRESULT;
const
    IID_IPersistFile: TGUID = (
        D1:$0000010B;D2:$0000;D3:$0000;D4:($C0,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00,$46));
begin
    Result := FALSE;
    if ALinkName = '' then
        Exit;

    hr := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink,
                           nil,
                           CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                           IID_IShellLink,
                           ISLink);
    if not Succeeded(hr) then
        Exit;

    hr := ISLink.QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, IPFile);
    if not Succeeded(hr) then
        Exit;

    ISLink.SetDescription(PChar(ADescription));
    ISLink.SetPath(PChar(ATargetName));
    ISLink.SetWorkingDirectory(PChar(ExtractFilePath(ATargetName)));
    ISLink.SetArguments(PChar(AArguments));

    ForceDirectories(ALinkFolder);
    LinkFileName := IncludeTrailingBackslash(ALinkFolder) +
                    ChangeFileExt(ALinkName,
                    '.lnk');

    DeleteFile(LinkFileName);
    if IPFile.Save(PChar(LinkFileName), FALSE) = S_OK then
        Result := TRUE;
end;
```

Example use:

```
CreateShellLink('C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe',
                'E:\Temp\BugReport1.txt',
                'C:\Users\MyUserCode\Desktop',
                'ShortcutTest',
                'Demo of CreateShellLink');
```

Of course, instead of hardcoded dektop folder, it is much better to query the system to get desktop folder. If you don't know how to do this and don't find by yourself, ask a separate question.

Applied to your question's data, the call becomes:

```
CreateShellLink('\\192.168.235.5\application\app.exe',
                '\\192.168.235.2:3050:C:\firebird\db.fdb',
                'C:\Users\MyUserCode\Desktop',
                'Databse access',
                'Use this shortcut to start database access');
```